# Insert Cassandra Query Error

Tags: cassandra

I am writing a simple insert query but getting error.

```
CREATE TABLE revenue_classification_region (
year int,
region text,
revenue_total int,
PRIMARY KEY (year,region));

INSERT INTO revenue_classification_region (year,region,revenue_total) VALUES (2015,’Western Europe’,5709);
```

Error:

```
Invalid syntax at line 1, char 84
  INSERT INTO revenue_classification_region (year,region,revenue_total) VALUES (2015,’Western Europe’,5709);
```

Please help

Answer (score 3):

The text value ('Western Europe') must be enclosed in normal simple quotes: `'`. Most probably this insert was copied from a web page in which the simple quote was replaced by one of the alternative quote characters.